# How can I prevent spaces in file names from causing the file name from appearing in the output when using graphicx?

Tags: graphics, external-files

I keep getting the file name of my images next to the image. For example:

[image]

- The full path of the file is `\\Shared Folders\courses\acce\14\exams\mtndfa.png`. From reading other tex.stackexchange questions, I found that the problem is almost certainly the space between "Shared" and "Folders". Unfortunately, as I'm using VMWare, I don't think there is much I can do about that name; that's the name VMWare gives it. (The files are on my Mac disk, but TeX is running under Windows on a VM.)
- I know I could compile on the Mac, but my editor (Scientific Workplace) is on Windows, so that's not very convenient.
- I also learned that using grffile might help; it didn't.
- Finally I learned that using quotes around the file name might help, but as the file name is relative, not absolute, the problem is not with the name as it is in my TeX file, but as it is after being made absolute.  Perhaps this is why griffle didn't help.

Here is the start of my file:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{grffile}%
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{30}%
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

---

EDIT: I found out that SWP is rewriting the `\includegraphics` command. I've updated the code below.

And, here is the `\includgraphics` command

```
\begin{figure}[ptb]%
\centering
\includegraphics[
natheight=0.866500in,
natwidth=1.886200in,
height=0.8994in,
width=1.9242in
]%
{//vmware-host/Shared Folders/courses/acce/14/exams/mtndfa.png}%
\end{figure}
```

**How can I prevent spaces in file names from causing the file name from appearing in the output when using  graphicx?**

Comment: How is tex finding the image? (It's hard to debug from fragments) If it is finding it on TEXINPUTS then I don't see how the path can end up in the document, the macro layer doesn't really know where the file is found? If you are using `\graphicspath` then there is the option of not using that, or using `"` should probably work.

Comment: I'm using TrueTeX, and I'm not sure what it does exactly.  I think that it is using TEXINPUTS. Presumable TrueTeX prepends the directory that the .tex file is in to its TEXINPUTS before really getting going.  In any case, the .png is in the same directory as the .tex and I am not using `\graphicspath`.  (I tried `\graphicspath{.}` but then I got the partial path in the output twice!)

Comment: well as I say it's very hard to debug given the information, if the file is in the current directory you could try using `{./mtndf.png}` see if that stops it adding the path. If all else fails add \tracingall immediately before the \includegraphics and post the resulting log

Comment: windows will also have an MSDOS style name for that directory with no spaces `dir /x` will list the long and short names.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle I'll try what you suggest.  There is certainly something very weird going on. I think it is specific to Scientific Workplace.  After playing about I found that If I have the problem in file x.tex and save the file as y.tex, the problem goes away. If I compare x.tex and y.tex, they are the same. If I close y.tex and then open it, the problem comes back.  So the problem is not in the file, but somehow with what SW does with it.

Comment: Use `\usepackage{grffile}`

Comment: @Harish Kumar. I am using grffile.

Comment: Voted unclear: log output was never added, and it's impossible to diagnose without this.

Comment: have you tried processing this job from the command line, without swp?  swp stopped using truetex several years ago; they now use tex live.  i don't know whether that would make any difference.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've been using TrueTeX as it is the devil I know. Probably it is time I switched to TeXLive.

In any case, my eventual solution was to rename VMWare's shared-folders drive to a name that has no spaces, as explained at https://communities.vmware.com/message/2294899#2294899 .